# How to get the font style used on the Dank Mono Font website in Atom?

Tags: css, atom-editor

On the website for the Dank Mono font: https://dank.sh/ fonts are formatted in the way shown
[image]

How do I get exactly the same style in Atom? I mean, what should I add to the styles.less file? I'd also like the comments to be in italic.

Comment: Try making it first yourself before you ask for help. I suggest reading up on less: http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy the Dank Mono font from [here](https://gumroad.com/l/dank-mono).

Download, then unzip it and install the two files `DankMono-Regular.ttf` and `DankMono-Italic.ttf`.

After that go to your code editor and in the font-family field type: **Dank Mono**.

That's all. Check your code & the Dank Mono font should have been applied.